# How can I make a Player object rotate using the A and D keys in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help as someone brand new to Unity and C# coding. The problem that I am currently facing is that I need my player model to only be able to rotate left and right instead of move on all three axis like many tutorials I have found online. The code I have currently got is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.left);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right);
    }

}
```

But the issue with this is that instead of rotating, the player physically moves left and right. Is anyone able to help with this? (preferably with some code)

Comment: Instead of `AddForce` use `AddTorque`..? Force is for movement ...

Comment: @derHugo this is closer but the player only moves up and down now

Comment: Then use the correct parameter ;) you probably want `Vector3.up * speed` and `Vector3.up * -speed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rigidboy, you can directly use the object's transform. So you won't have any problems.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float turnSpeed;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
           transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * turnSpeed);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
           transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * turnSpeed);
    }
}
```